# Building android source fails due to openjdk java version

Tags: android

I am trying to build andorid source tree using unbuntu13.10 on intel-corei7 installed on windows 8 system (replaced windows 8 with ubuntu).
Builing source has some issue related to java jdk version.

Any suggestion or hint on what might be wrong would be of help. 
The html file the error refers is not of much help.

Issue#
After I checkout the source tree as master, using "repo init" and "repo sync"
 I am attempting to build using:

```
         . build/envsetup.sh
         lunch aosp_arm-eng
         make -j4
```

getting below error:

```
    You are attempting to build with an unsupported JDK.
    You use OpenJDK but only Sun/Oracle JDK is supported. Please follow the machine setup instructions at https://source.android.com/source/download.html
    build/core/main.mk:175: * stop. Stop.
```

1. verified that my root directory has below path with all the required java libraries.

   ```
    mydir@mydir-laptop:/usr/lib/jvm$ ls java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64 
    java-1.7.0- openjdk-amd64 java-6-openjdk-amd64 
    java-6-openjdk-common java-7-openjdk-amd64
   ```

While my source is at path /home/mydir/WORKING_DIRECTORY
tried copying /usr/lib/jvm from root to /home/mydir still see the same error.

2. verified main.mk: The macro is set and hence requires_openjdk is false and is hitting ifneq part and fails.

   ```
    EXPERIMENTAL_USE_JAVA7 requires_openjdk := false 
    ifneq ($(shell java -version 2>&1 | grep -i openjdk),)
   ```
3. Java version details:

   ```
   java version "1.7.0_51" 
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea2.4.4)    
    (7u51-2.4.4-0ubuntu0.13.10.1) 
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
   ```
4. verified envsetup.sh has the code pointing to

   ```
    java-7-openjdk-amd64 
    if [ ! "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then 
    if [ ! "$EXPERIMENTAL_USE_JAVA7" ]; then case uname -s in Darwin) 
    export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions /1.6/Home ;; *) 
    export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun ;;
    esac else case uname -s in Darwin) 
    export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home ;; *) 
    export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64 ;; 
    esac fi

   # Keep track of the fact that we set JAVA_HOME ourselves, so that 
   # we can change it on the next envsetup.sh, if required. 
   export ANDROID_SET_JAVA_HOME=true fi }
   ```

Comment: building EXPERIMENTAL_USE_JAVA7 set to true resolved this issue.

Comment: which branch are you using? i just downloaded `android-4.4.3_r1.1` and its make files do not even check for that var. it simply fails as soon as it find openjdk in the version string.

Comment: How to set EXPERIMENTAL_USE_JAVA7 to true ?

Comment: The Android build now fully supports Java 7 (and requires it for Lollipop).